# Is it possible to declare a pure virtual function with deduced return type? If not, why not?

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, decltype, pure-virtual

I have some abstract class, and I wonder whether I could declare a function with this signature inside it:

```
virtual auto some_function() = 0;
```

In case it helps answering, I'm trying to implement a class that will allow to register callbacks for different types, so that when a member template function is called, it will look for its argument's `typeid` in an associative container and call its associated callback on it.

JUSTIFICATION FOR THE ORIGINALITY OF THE QUESTION

According to [N3638 - Return type deduction for normal functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html)

> It would be possible to allow return type deduction for virtual
>   functions (...)

so while auto virtual is not allowed in C++, **it is a possible alternative design according to Jason Merrill**.

So this question: **Is it possible to declare a pure virtual function with deduced return type? If not, why not?** (I have fixed the title to match the real question and its intent) is not the same as the answer to the question **Is it possible to declare a virtual function with deduced return type?**

Maybe it would help if moderators considered the question and not just its title.

Comment: Alright, I was aware that most likely it would not be possible to do so. Now that I know for sure, any help with the other part of my post?

Comment: I don't understand the use case. Some code of how you want to use it? The answer is probably some template magic.

Comment: @Dani Tell us what you are trying to do (NOT how you want to do it), even some incorrect pseudo code might help.

Comment: Solved. Thanks anyway. If you're still curious just tell me, if not, there's no point on posting the code.

Comment: After `auto x = base->some_function();` what would the type of `x` be? You don't know which derived type `base` represents, so you cannot consult the derived type.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It still isn't a dup.

Comment: Can someone reopen this question?

Comment: @Dani I am still curious.

Comment: @Dani Do you understand the relation between auto and decltype?

Comment: Sorry, @curiousguy, I hadn't seen these answers. It kind of worked for me until I tested it a little bit more. I think I'm posting it in a different question. I'll let you know about it.

Comment: @curiousguy, I finally got some working code. It is a tiny library for a personal project. It isn't finished yet, I plan to add some more features and improve it. In case you want to see the code: https://github.com/danigit/DataStore . Any comment will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

**The question does not make sense.** `auto` means deduced from initialization:

```
auto i = 1; // int
```

or deduced from `return` statement:

```
auto f() { return 2; } // int
```

A pure virtual function *by definition* does not have a definition of a virtual function (*), so it does not have a `return` statement, **so the return type could not be deduced from anything**.

You must have an incorrect understanding of C++ to think this could work.

**Short answer:** C++ is statically typed.

ADDITIONAL DETAIL

Note (*): A pure virtual function can have definition, but it is the
   definition of a non-virtual function callable with the scope
   resolution operator:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

void Base::f() {
    std::cout << "Base::f()\n";
}

struct Der : Base {
    virtual void f();
};

void Der::f() {
    cout << "Der::f()\n";
}

int main() {
    Der d;
    d.Base::f();
}
```

Test [here](http://ideone.com/pZaQ9J); outputs:

```
Base::f()
```

OTOH, `Base::f()` can't be called via the virtual call mechanism:

```
struct Base {
    Base ();
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

void call (Base *p) {
    cout << "Base::Base()\n";
    p->f();
}

Base::Base () {
    call(this);
}
```

Test [here](http://ideone.com/852Kcy); generates:

```
Runtime error
```

**The pure virtual function can't be called virtually.**

A pure virtual function return type could be deduced from the return statement of the non-virtual definition (**), but it would create another special case and it wouldn't solve the present problem (the return statement is not known in the base class).

(**) A virtual function can't be declared `auto` in C++, but there is not strong reason to disallow `auto` virtual function.

REPLY TO COMMENT

> The return type could be hypothetically deduced from a derived class'
>   implementation.

OK, let's say we do that:

```
struct Base {
    virtual auto f() = 0;
};

struct Der1 : Base {
    virtual int f();
};
```

Then the return type of `Base::f()` is int, right? This is assuming that Der can be found in the compiler, even if it is latter defined, elsewhere, and the program is compiled separately (or maybe you suggest this feature wouldn't be compatible with separate compilation?). Now the class can be derived elsewhere:

```
struct Der2 : Base {
    virtual std::string f();
};
```

So what is the type of return type of `Base::f()`? int, string, neither, both, a [cat](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/97713/schr%C3%B6dingers-cat-why-was-it-necessary)?

In C++ an expression must have a well defined type: a **declared** type, aka **compile time** type, aka **static** type. These words are equivalent.

For example, a pointer variable declare type never changes, not does the declared type of `*p`, but the real aka runtime aka dynamic type of `*p` depends on the value of `p`:

```
Base *p = 0; 

// declared type of p is Base*, real type of *p is Base, 
// declared type of *p is Base, real type of *p is undefined
cout << "typeid (p): " << typeid (p).name() << "\n";

p = new Der1; 
// declared type of p is Base*, real type of *p is Base, 
// declared type of *p is Base, real type of *p is Der1
cout << "typeid (p): " << typeid (p).name() << "\n";
cout << "typeid (*p): " << typeid (*p).name() << "\n";
```

The declared type is used by the compiler:

- for name lookup
- for overload resolution (overloaded non member functions, overloaded member functions, overloaded operators)
- for member access checking (`public`, `protected`, `private`)

The real type controls the runtime virtual call behavior.

The distinction of declared vs. real type is one of the most important C++ concepts!

Comment: The return type could be hipothetically deduced from a derived class' implementation. The fact that a pure virtual function does not have a return statement shouldn't be a problem, as abstract classes can't be instantiated. That was how I had thought it could work in case it did. Seems like it would create much more problems than it would solve, though.

Comment: Which derived class? A regular function that is used in the program must have exactly one definition. **A class can have zero or more derived classes.** How the compiler would find the derived class? In which TU (translation unit)? Would you require the derived class to be defined right after the base class?

Comment: In such case, there would be a different function with a different signature for each of the derived classes. Obviously it wouldn't be the same function, as each one is scoped to its class. For the three last questions, I'm not an expert in compiler or language implementation details. Anyway, at this point I have understood that it wouldn't be a very sensible thing to do, and that it doesn't fit with C++'s statically typed nature. Thanks for pointing me out why.

Comment: @Dani The signature is the function name + argument list + constness. Return type is not part of the signature.

Comment: "A pure virtual function by definition does not have a definition of a virtual function" -- false.  A pure virtual function can have a definition.  `struct X { virtual void foo()=0; };  void X::foo() { std::cout << "hello world\n"; }`

Comment: @Yakk Wrong. The definition of a pure **virtual** is not the definition of the **virtual** function.

Comment: @curiousguy Either the words you are using don't mean what I think they mean, or you are mistaken.  [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35a37c56499594cb), containing the code I wrote in my last comment verbatim.  `X::foo` is pure virtual, and defined.  A pure virtual function can have a definition.  It is unusual, but legal, and it works.  Pure virtual means "child must override" and "definition is *optional*", not "does not have a definition".  It is a common (and undestandable!) error to believe it means "does not have a definition", but that is false.

Comment: @Yakk I am not mistaken and my words mean exactly what I mean. The definition is not a **definition of virtual function**.

Comment: Ok.  In my [example (link)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35a37c56499594cb), `X::foo` virtual?  Is it a virtual function?  Is `X::foo` defined?  I'm trying to figure out what you think is happening.  My working hypothesis is Dunning-Kruger based, but I'm willing to be disproven.  Repeating what you say **in bold** does not, however, convince.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87047/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-yakk).

Comment: @Dani I have modified my answer to explain declared vs. real type

Comment: Thanks for dedicating some time to post such a detailed answer. I really appreciate it as an inexpert but enthusiast programmer.